# How can I play on the League of Legends PBE (beta server)

Tags: league-of-legends

I saw some YouTube videos with people playing champions before they were released.
How can I do that too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before September 2012, PBE signups were open to all summoners.

From September 2012 to December 2012, PBE signups were open on the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd of each month.

From January 2013 onward, Riot decided not to hold scheduled PBE signups, due to the large amount of players.

As of this writing (October 2013), PBE signups are open, ostensibly to prepare to test Season 4 features.

Additionally, the PBE structure has changed. PBE will now have registrations in rounds, and the majority of accounts will be disabled at the end of each round. (**There is no longer permanent access to PBE.**) <sup>[(source)](http://forums.na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=3969097)</sup>

There are also new restrictions on who is able to create a PBE account:

> We have a few guidelines to help you decide if you'd be a good fit for the PBE:
>
> 1. Your live account is level 30.
> 2. You have a pretty clean history of bans and reports.
> 3. You enjoy talking through your experiences - sometimes with people who don't share your opinion.

It's also worthwhile to note that PBE can no longer be signed up for *per se*; rather, Riot will select from a pool of applicants. For instance, players who tend to play Mages are more likely to be selected when testing a new Mage.

If PBE signups are open (for which you can [check the status](http://community.pbe.leagueoflegends.com/f/2EAF660193FA3B668D7234B3AEBB530C5AB7F651/d/A6C28D2F095DB73F105D1B3CD30386864E6D77FF)), then you can sign up for an account [here](https://pbesignup.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/pbe).

Comment: I want to note that despite my not being super active on PBE, my access has yet to be revoked, so non-permanent access may not be entirely true.

Answer (score 9):

This appears to be the url to sign up for access to the public beta server:

https://pbe.leagueoflegends.com/en/signup/index

The beta server is only NA, so there is no EUW etc. equivalent. As mentioned by Schism, it is no longer permanent access and you need to apply each round to get in. Riot has stated that you may be more likely to get access based on contributions (e.g. bug reports) during past rounds in PBE.

Comment: hey, could it be that you cant register anymore ?

Comment: @Gigala Since this answer, they've pretty much closed signups. They did a 3 day long sign up the beginning of December 2012, but no sign-ups since then. They want it to be exclusive, not just open to anyone.

Comment: The server is NA, but that doesn't mean you can't play on it if you have an account. It just means you'll have a high ping when playing from the EU for example.

Answer (score 3):

You can only sign up for the Public Beta Environment on the 1st, 2nd, or 3rd of each month.

See this thread for more information: http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?p=28042411